# Documenting Rest APIs in Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I am very new to Vertx. Could someone let me know , if there is a way to document the Rest Apis. Having it with swagger is possible but I am looking for something to write within the router code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you mean by "something to write within the router code", but there are two projects in Vert.x space for Swagger documentation:

1. https://github.com/phiz71/vertx-swagger - you write Swagger, it generates routes for you
2. https://github.com/anupsaund/vertx-auto-swagger - you write Java annotations, it generates Swagger

Both aren't maintained, though, so I cannot trully recommend any of them.